# Configuration fault for react/remix i18n

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I need some help configuring i18next library in a remix project. For the life of me I can't figure out what the misonconfiguration is but none of my keys are resolving on server side (they're fine on the client).

I followed the instructions on this page:
https://github.com/sergiodxa/remix-i18next

Using the remix Blues Mix starter.

locales are in /public/locales/en/common.json and /es/common.json

I've debugged it and I can see loadpath is resolved to the correct directory in i18next-fs-backend.

But every time it hits a translation, it reports the key wasn't found in the debug.

`i18next::translator: missingKey en common shopping-bag shopping-bag`

I'm really struggling to understand why the locale string aren't resolving.

```js
// i18n.config.ts
export default {
  
  // This is the list of languages your application supports
  supportedLngs: ["en", "es"],
  // This is the language you want to use in case
  // if the user language is not in the supportedLngs
  fallbackLng: "en",
  // The default namespace of i18next is "translation", but you can customize it here
  defaultNS: "common",
  // Disabling suspense is recommended
  react: { useSuspense: false },
};
```

```js
// i18next.server.js
import Backend from "i18next-fs-backend";
import { resolve } from "node:path";
import { RemixI18Next } from "remix-i18next";
import i18n from "~/i18n.config"; // your i18n configuration file


let i18next = new RemixI18Next({
  detection: {
    supportedLanguages: i18n.supportedLngs,
    fallbackLanguage: i18n.fallbackLng,
  },
  // This is the configuration for i18next used
  // when translating messages server-side only
  i18next: {
    ...i18n,
    backend: {
      loadPath: resolve("./public/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json"),
    },
  },
  // The backend you want to use to load the translations
  // Tip: You could pass `resources` to the `i18next` configuration and avoid
  // a backend here
  backend: Backend,
});

export default i18next;
```

```js
// root.tsx
import { cssBundleHref } from "@remix-run/css-bundle";
import type { LinksFunction, LoaderArgs } from "@remix-run/node";
import {
  Links,
  LiveReload,
  Meta,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
  useLoaderData
} from "@remix-run/react";

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import tailwindStylesheetUrl from "~/styles/tailwind.css";
import { CartContext } from "./lib/context/cart-context";
import { ThemeContext } from "./lib/context/theme";
import { UserContext } from "./lib/context/user";
import { getSiteConfiguration } from "./models/siteconfig.model";
import { optionalUser } from "./session.server";
import DefaultLayout from "./ui/templates/page";

export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
  { rel: "stylesheet", href: tailwindStylesheetUrl },
  ...(cssBundleHref ? [{ rel: "stylesheet", href: cssBundleHref }] : []),
];

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
  const user = await optionalUser(request);
  const siteConfig = await getSiteConfiguration();

  return {siteConfig: siteConfig, _user: user };
};

export default function App() {
  // Get the locale from the loader
  // @ts-expect-error can't figure out how to make this work
  const { locale, siteConfig, _user, _cart } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()
  const { menu } = siteConfig
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = React.useState(false)
  const [showSearch, setShowSearch] = React.useState(false)
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState(_cart)
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(_user)
  const [nav] = React.useState(menu)

  function toggleCart() {
    setShowCart(!showCart)
  }

  function toggleSearch() {
    setShowSearch(!showSearch)
  }
  const themeContext = { nav, showCart, toggleCart, showSearch, toggleSearch }
  const userContext = { user, setUser }
  const cartContext = { cart, setCart }

  useEffect(() => {
    setCart(_cart)
  }, [_cart, _cart?.id])

  return (
    <html lang="en" className="h-full">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body className="h-full">
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={themeContext}>
          <UserContext.Provider value={userContext}>
            <CartContext.Provider value={cartContext}>
            <DefaultLayout />
            </CartContext.Provider>
          </UserContext.Provider>
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the handle export in `root.tsx` and my other routes.

Needed to add this to the route files.

```
export let handle = {
  i18n: ["common","footer"] // these are the namespaces used by the routes.
};
```

I'll leave the question here in case someone has the same problem

Comment: I have recently split my growing `common.json` files into page-specific files. On the client side this caused a short display of the translation keys before the page-specific json was loaded and the text was then translated. 
My `handle` object only contained `i18n: 'common'`. This answer helped to fix this by changing it to an array and specifying all namespaces. Thank you!